# php mail script not working using phpMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, fat-free-framework

I am using phpMailer to send emails using PHP.
The mail is being sent but it is not received in inbox/spam or anything.
It is surprising that it was working until few days ago.
I have tested it and almost 500-600 emails were sent and received. 
But suddenly it stopped "working".

Here's my Php script:

```
public static function mailTo($recipients)
{
    $f3 = \Base::instance();
    $edit = $f3->get('editTrue');
    $user = AclHelper::getCurrentUser();
    $template= new \Template;
    if(isset($edit))
    {
        $mailBody = $template->render('leave/requestEdit.html');
    }
    else
    {
        $mailBody= $template->render('leave/emailTemp.html');
    }

    // When true, PHPMailer returns exceptions
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    try {
        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->isHTML(true);

        $mail->addAddress($user['email']);
        $mail->addAddress("malakar.rakesh1993@gmail.com");

        // foreach($recipients as $recipient){
        //     $mail->addCC($recipient);
        // }

        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
        $mail->Username = "malakar.rakesh1993@gmail.com";
        $mail->Password = "abcd";

        // $mail->Host = $f3->get('GBD.smtp.host');   // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->setFrom($user['email']);

        $userFullName = trim(ucfirst($user['firstname'])) . " " . trim(ucfirst($user['lastname']));
        $mail->FromName = $userFullName;
        $mail->Body =  $f3->get('message');
        $mail->Body .="<br>". $mailBody;

        if(isset($edit))
        {
            $mail->AltBody = '';
        }
        else
        {
            $mail->AltBody = 'Hello Team,<br>I would like to request leave for the leave dates specified as follows.
        Application Date:' . $f3->get('issuedDate') . '<br>Leave requested from:' . $f3->get('leaveFrom') . '<br>Leave requested to:' . $f3->get('leaveTo') . '<br>Leave Description:' . $f3->get('leaveDescription') . 'Leave Type:' . $f3->get('leaveType').'<br><br>Hoping for a positive response.<br><br> Thank you.';
        }

        $mail->Subject = 'Updates on leave date applied';

        $mailStatus = (boolean)$mail->send();

        if ($mailStatus === true) {
            return $mail;
        }
    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        $response = array(
            'status'=>'error',
            'message'=>'Got some error while sending emails',
            'exceptions'=>$e->getMessage()
        );
        return $response;

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $response = array(
            'status'=>'error',
            'message'=>'Got some error while sending emails',
            'exceptions'=>$e->getMessage()
        );

        return $response;
    }
}
```

I received a junk email though [only one] that says :

```
This sender failed our fraud detection checks and may not be who they appear to be. Learn about spoofing
```

I cannot figure out what's going wrong.

It is working until previously. And I have tons of emails in my inbox.

Could it be that there's some limit of sending emails?? Or could it be that some one reported it as spam or spoofing??

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Set $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; to debug and see the client server responses

Comment: Where can I find the output?

Comment: just try to echo the "mailTo" function's output

Comment: `$mail->setFrom($user['email']);`... Does it mean you send messages from arbitrary senders? If that's the case, I suspect Gmail is not amused. I mean, what if you write `trump@whitehouse.gov`? They can't authenticate that.

Comment: I have recently learnt about that too.. and other spoofing stuffs.. but that had been working until few days ago.... How do I fix that??

Comment: I can't think of a way to spoof senders, apart from switching to a SMTP provider less concerned about security. Perhaps you'd need to rethink why you need that in the first place (I don't really know your use case).

Comment: I mean how do I set sender's address??

Comment: You set sender's address with `$mail->setFrom()`.

Comment: isn't that the same what I did??

Comment: Yes, that's the same you did. But you asked how to do it right here in comments. :-? (This must be some misunderstanding.)

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using `SMTPSecure = 'ssl'` you won't get any debug output with `SMTPDebug = 2` because that only shows SMTP-level output; You need `SMTPDebug = 3`  to show connection-level problems. This is probably caused by out of date CA certificates in your PHP config. There have been lots of reports of this because gmail changed theirs recently (why your script stopped working). It's covered in [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Also, why are you putting HTML tags in your plan-text `AltBody`? They won't work in there.

Comment: out of date CA certificates? It is working in server.. but not working in my localhost... The server is also using the same code...

Comment: Read carefully: **CA certificates**. These are not the certificates presented by the server when you connect; they are the certificates that your server has already and uses to check that the cert that came from the server is valid. Your result tells me that one of them is up to date, the other is not. It's your OS and PHP config that's at fault - nothing to do with your code.

Comment: I'm getting this PHPmailer Exception : SMTP() connect failed.. is it related with CA cert issue? Also, it was working until few days ago... thought I would notify you ...

Comment: Yes. As I said - gmail changed their certificate, and you need up to date CA certs to verify the new one. That’s why it stopped working.